# Load image in bPopup

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, bpopup

I have an ajax call for a progress bar for a file upload. This works fine. I tried to add a line to have bPopup open the image afterwards but I can't get it working.

This is my javascript:

```
ajax.addEventListener("load", completeHandler, false);

function completeHandler(e) {
    var fileDest = e.target.responseText;
    uploadedImg = new Image();
    uploadedImg.src = fileDest;
    _("uploadedImg").src=fileDest; // All above here works
    $('uploadedImg').bPopup();     // This doesn't
    _("progressBar").value = 0;    // This also works
}
```

I get no errors from javascript in the console in chrome. I have jquery 1.4.2 and bpopup files correctly linked.

HTML:

```
<img id="uploadedImg" src=""> // 'display:none' in css file
```

I have followed instructions on this page http://dinbror.dk/blog/bPopup/#Usage and cannot see what I have done wrong.

Comment: what is the error you are receiving ?

Comment: I'm not recieving an error, it just isn't loading the lightbox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, fixed it :)

1. Put `<img>` in a div
2. Linked bpopup css `http://dinbror.dk/bpopup/assets/style.min.css`
3. Linked jquery.easing `http://dinbror.dk/bpopup/assets/jquery.easing.1.3.js`
4. Added missing # to `$('uploadedImg').bPopup();`

Answer (score 1):

you have an error in calling your jquery

let's say you have a button or an a tag with id `demo` for example.In jquery you should call it like this : `$("#demo")` here you are calling it like this : `$('uploadedImg').bPopup();`

try to fix it to be like this : `$('#uploadedImg').bPopup();`  and try again

Comment: Found that and some other issues just before you posted, thanks!